# If $f(ab)f(ac)f(bc)f(a+b)f(a+c)f(b+c)=2015$ for every positive (non-zero) $a$, $b$ and $c$, find $f(2016)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $f(ab)f(ac)f(bc)f(a+b)f(a+c)f(b+c)=2015$ for every positive (non-zero) $a$, $b$ and $c$, find $f(2016)$.

Can someone help me?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I saw that 2015=5.13.31 and tried do apply that to the equation. But I couldn't get any further. :(

Comment: What is $f$? A polynomial function, a general function, or other?

Comment: Any kind of function

Comment: $f(4)=\sqrt[6]{2015}$

Comment: Thanks guys!!! I understood it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$a=b=c=1\to f(1)f(2)=\sqrt[3]{2015}\\
a=c=1\to f(1)f(2)f(b)^2f(b+1)^2=2015\to f(b)f(b+1)=\sqrt[3]{2015}\\
a=b=c=2\to f(4)=\sqrt[6]{2015}\\
f(n)=\sqrt[6]{2015}\text{ by induction}$$

Answer (score 3):

$$f(ab)\cdot f(ac)\cdot f(bc)\cdot f(a+b)\cdot f(a+c)\cdot f(b+c)=2015\\a=b=c=0\\f(0)^6=2015\\f(0)=\sqrt[6]{2015}\\b=c=0\\f(0)^4\cdot f(a)^2=2015\\f(a)=\sqrt{\frac{2015}{\sqrt[6]{2015^4}}}=\sqrt{2015^{2/6}}=\sqrt[6]{2015}$$

Comment: We are given $a,b,c$ are all positive.

Comment: My mistake I haven't read the non-zero part.Gonna edit

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that $f$ is a general function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ and give a shortcut solution.

One function that clearly satisfies your condition is $f(x)=\sqrt[6]{2015}$ for all $x$. (I got this by assuming $f(x)$ is constant and solving for that constant.) If your answer has a definite solution, it will also hold for this function.

Therefore, we have $f(2016)=\sqrt[6]{2015}\approx 3.553959778416656970$. If my assumption of a definite solution is off, this is at least a possible solution.